# Amelia (error if I include categorical vars)

Tags: r, data-imputation

If I include a categorical variable in amelia (e.g., p3[,4]), I am getting the following error:

```
a.out <- amelia(p3[,-5], noms=p3[,4],m = 10, ts = "time", cs = "Username")
Error in if (any(vars > AMp, vars < 0, vars%%1 != 0)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(vars, AMp) : > not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(vars, 0) : < not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(vars, 1) : %% not meaningful for factors
```

If I replace this variable as continuous, then the imputed values are outside the observed range (e.g., negative). I would appreciate it of you could help to understand why I can't incorporate categorical variables.

Thanks,
Y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for `amelia` (*Amelia II*) package to work correctly with *categorical variables*, you need to specify corresponding variables as such **explicitly**. In particular, for *nominal* and *ordinal* categorical variables, you need to specify corresponding vectors in separate arguments `noms` and `ords`:

> **noms**
>       a vector of numbers or names indicating columns in the data that are nominal variables.
>
> **ords**    a vector of numbers or names indicating columns in the data that should be treated as ordinal variables.

The above-presented snippet is from `amelia()` [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/Amelia/docs/amelia). More details on the support for categorical variables in `amelia` can be found in [the package's vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/vignettes/amelia.pdf) in sections 4.4.1 and 4.4.2.